# How to get all values inside a div as a string using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have an html that i need to extract just a div and the elements inside this div but as a string.

```
 <div id=01>
    <div id-02>
      <label></labell>
      <input></input>
       //etc
     </div>
 </div>
```

How do i get all inside the div 01 as a single string?

The only way i found is to get using the nodes, but it returns me a collection of HtmlNodes.

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'container')]").Descendants("div").Select(p => p.OuterHtml);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var Node = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='01']").SingleOrDefault();
var target = Node.InnerHtml;
```

becouse id is single I used SingleOrDefault for this id

Comment: @ggui if my answer resolved your problem accept it as correct one, otherwise explain your new problem with my answer in a comment for discussing about it. tanx.